# The differential equation $y' = \frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, logarithms

In my university, the integral calculus teacher gave me this differential equation to solve.

$$ y' = \frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} $$

I don't have any clue of what form the solution of this differential equation has.

Comment: Is this seperable?

Comment: @MichaelCera, no this ODE is not separable.

Comment: Yeah this appears to be a nonlinear, first-order ODE. Not certain regarding techniques for solution.

Comment: What if you use the change of variables $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$? In that case, you'd get $$y' = \frac{2\log r}{r^2}$$ and further on, $$\int y' = \int \frac{2\log r}{r^2}$$ so $$y  = -2\frac{\log r + 1}{r}.$$ I am not sure whether this is valid.

Comment: @bgsk : No, it isn't valid : $$y=\int y'dx=\int\frac{2\ln(r)}{r^2}dx \neq \int\frac{2\ln(r)}{r^2}dr =-2\frac{\ln(r)+1}{r}$$ $$y \neq -2\frac{\ln(r)+1}{r}$$

Comment: @user291192 : The clue might be to use numerical calculus to solve it. Or the true question isn't to solve it, but to answer to another question without need to solve it. Or your  integral calculus teacher might be a kidder...

Comment: A quick remark: let $u(x) = y(x) + ix$, then the initial problem can be stated as
$$
\frac{u' +\bar u'}{2} = \frac{\ln(u)}{u} \cdot \frac{\ln(\bar u)}{\bar u}
$$
(express $x^2 + y^2$ as $u\bar u$, recover the solution as $\Re u$)

Comment: Did we try stack overflow?

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment because I don't have enough points but this is what I came up with.

If we assume $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and $x=r\cos(\theta)$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = a\tan(y/x)$ then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}r}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}x}=[\text{calculations}]=0.
$$
Inserting this in the given ODE we get $r^2=x^2+y^2=1$. But this feels wrong. Please comment if you guys know where I made a mistake.

Comment: I just realized how old this question is. If you know the answer now please let me know.

Comment: I like this, but why are you setting $dy/dx$ equal to zero?

Comment: @SherwinLott Because if you carry out the calculation that is inserting all the derivatives it all equals to zero.

Comment: (Okay, I had misinterpreted and thought you were *setting* it equal to zero.)  Yes, something must have gone wrong in the calculations since we know $dy/dx$ is not zero unless $r=1$. When you computed $dr/dx$ and $d\theta/dx$ did you account for the fact that $r$ and $\theta$ are a function of $y$ which depends on $x$?  E.g. Did you differentiate $y^{2}$ (in the equation for $r$) with respect to $x$ when doing the chain rule?

Comment: @SherwinLott oooh that is true, no I didn't do that. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I will redo the calculations and comment/change my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A differential geometric approach for numerical integration is used as no analytical solution seems possible.

Using polar coordinates differentiation with respect to ***four variables*** arc length, two polar coordinates and connecting parameter $\psi$ as shown in the exaggerated differential elements triangle

$$s,\;dr/ds=\cos\psi, r d\theta/ds= \sin \psi,dy/dx= \tan \phi \tag 1$$

[image: differential triangle]

$$ \phi=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\log r^2}{r^2} \tag1$$

Differentiating with respect to arc, the curvature

$$ =\dfrac{ d\phi}{ds} =2\; \dfrac{\cos \psi}{r}\cdot\dfrac{1-\log r^2}{r^2+(\log (r^2)/r)^2} \tag2 $$

From the above figure we have $ \phi= \psi+\theta$ so that this equals

$$=\dfrac{d\theta+ d\psi}{ds} =\psi'+ \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}=2 \dfrac{\cos \psi}{r}\cdot\dfrac{1-\log r^2}{r^2+(\log (r^2)/r)^2} \tag3$$

Inflection points occur at radius $\sqrt{e}$ at zero curvature.

Integration has initial conditions in the center of interval at start point or "Nose" point (for lack of a classical term known to me) as $\psi=0,r=r_i$ and integrates numerically on either side of this start point.

*Nose point or Power Tangent point*

The "nose" can be defined for any continuous curve in the plane in one of the three following ways:

$$ \psi=0\quad; \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}; \quad \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta \tag4 $$

The powers of a circle

$$ T^2= (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2-R^2$$

are obtained by setting $(x=y=0)$ to be $T^2= h^2+k^2-R^2$

According as the circle is outside, passes through origin or inside of the origin powers correspond to

$$T^2>0,\;T^2=0,\;T^2<0\;;$$

*Plot of Curves*

[image: Full Curves]

Tangency at the nose of curves at $(r_i=0,0.25,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.50\;)$are marked.

For these curves we have all powers **$r_i^2=T^2$ positive.**

Comment: Why can't $r$ be less than $1$?  It'd just make the slope negative?  It just can't go through the origin, i.e. $y(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Shown  in update $r \ge ri$ what I meant.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, how are you getting a solution that is not a one-to-one function?  Like, just because $y'$ is negative when $r^{2} < 1$ doesn't mean it curves backwards? I understand how parametric equations (especially in polar coordinates) can produce these kinds of shapes, but that shouldn't be going on here?  No matter what $y'$ is we should still get a one-to-one function?

Comment: I have not made the ode parametric now. Anyhow I think in view of the update old introductory para is redundant , shall delete it. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how the solution can in some cases not be a one-to-one function?

Comment: Integration done with several boundary conditions. Why should the solution be one-to-one?

Comment: Because $y'$ is well defined and continuous everywhere (except at $y(0)=0$). Therefore, your solutions that have points where $y' = -\infty$ cannot be correct.  Also, some of the slopes are positive even when $r^{2} < 1$, which can't be right since: $\log(r^{2})/r^{2} < 0$.

Comment: @Integrand At a more basic level, every vector in the associated field is pointing to the right (except at the origin).  Any solution to the differential equation must therefore be a one-to-one function.

Comment: ϕ,θ,ψ can assume any values. They c an point anywhere.For clarity I labelled all angles in the sketch.

Comment: The second graph doesn't look right for $ri=1.25$. At $x \approx 2$, $y \approx 2$, the slope should be $\approx 0.26$ but the slope in the graph looks like $\approx 1$.

Comment: I agree with Sherwin Lott's comment; I fail to see how these graphs can be correct if the DE is well-defined.

Comment: @xidgel. Included full domain$\theta$ polar coordinate in graph.

Comment: @Integrand: The solutions of ode are one-to-one continuous at $r=r_i.$ As stated earlier. I had plotted  for seeing behaviour only between $r_i<r <\infty$ without curve crowdings in  $r \lt r_i$. Now the  full domain curve is drawn. Hope it clarifies the one-to- one, both ways mappable  smooth continuity situation.

Comment: @SherwinLott: Has the full curve now one to one correspondence  to the ode?

Comment: I've been assuming your axes are $x$ and $y$ (an earlier version was labeled that way).  Are the axes $r$ and $\theta$?  That would likely explain away the one-to-one problem I'm having.  (If they are $x$ and $y$, then I'm still having the same problem as before.  Some of the curves have multiple values of $y$ for certain values of $x$.)

Comment: But regardless of axes, how can the curves cross each other? The derivative at any point of intersection must be the same, it doesn't depend on which curve we are on?

Comment: I'm trying to understand it from your differential geometry approach.  All your math makes sense to me up to and including $\psi'+ \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}$, but I don't follow the next step?

Comment: I still don't fully understand what these curves mean

Comment: So I have edited. Please comment where exactly you are not able to follow. Still there is time including grace time.

Comment: I double checked the math in the first three equations, and I think I found one mistake?
$$\dfrac{ d\phi}{ds} =2\; \dfrac{\cos \psi}{r}\cdot\dfrac{1-\log r^2}{r^2+(\log r^2)^2/r^2}$$
This differs in the "$/r^{2}$" term of the denominator.  I don't know if that fundamentally changes the graphs?

Comment: Thanks for checking the ode. There is a minor change in graph seen after correcting typo. But I am not still quite happy with the  accuracy obtained  particularly with $r_i<1$ cases. Normally I obtain numerical zeroes as good as $10^{-6}.$ Need more time to fix it. However I hope I could present the basic behaviour of the integrand curve .

Answer (score 4):

I would say to simply draw the vector field.  Inside the unit circle, $y'$ is negative, so the flow vectors are down and to the right.  On the unit circle, $y'=0$, so the flow vectors are horizontal there.  Outside the unit circle, the flow vectors are up and to the right (though they become close to horizontal far from the unit circle).  So the solutions are essentially constant functions (increasing very slowly) for very positive and very negative initial values of $y$.  For intermediate initial values of $y,$ we will see an upward slope approaching the unit circle from left to right, a downward dive passing through the unit circle, and then an upward slope again after leaving the unit circle.  There is one solution, symmetric under a $180^\circ$ rotation, where $y\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

---

*Update*.  The attached figure shows approximately what the solutions look like.  I misstated the behavior of the symmetric solution; it does not necessarily approach $y=0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, but rather has two asymptotes, $y=\pm y_\infty$.

[image]

Comment: If you have the capability to produce such pictures, I would be interested in seeing them.

Comment: I’ve added an image showing a family of solutions obtained by numerical integration of the ODE; the initial conditions were equally spaced along the $y$-axis.